# Do more Results

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm learning php and mysql and to time I have finally my dynamic menu ready. Now I want use a news system. For this I have write a simple script in php with a while loop

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($row = $resut->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><th>". $row["ntitle"]."</th></tr><tr><th>". $row["ninhalt"]."</th></tr><tr><th>". $row["ndatum"]."</th></tr>";
    }
}
```

I use

```
<?php

require_once ('config.php');

$db_link = mysqli_connect (MYSQL_HOST, 
                       MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                       MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                       MYSQL_DATENBANK);

if ( $db_link )
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, mtitle, mlink FROM cm_menue";
    $result = $db_link->query($sql);

}
else
{
// hier sollte dann später dem Programmierer eine
// E-Mail mit dem Problem zukommen gelassen werden
die('keine Verbindung möglich: ' . mysqli_error());
}
?>
```

For my Database Connect and for do mysql data select, so I can't can use $sql again. How do I make it so that I can select other data that I need for the news system?

Comment: you could put all the code from the 2nd block in one config file to include as needed - at least i think that is what you are asking

Comment: Jeah my english is not so good, sry show i mean for my menue i use the $sql . now i want for my news system select other data but i dont know how i now can do this

Comment: Please share complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a news system I guess you need data from another table which has references to another table with an id or something like that. In that case you should use a join.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

If not, you can just declare another variable like $sql2 and use it.